# Breaking out of layouts in SvelteKit (release candidate version)

Tags: sveltekit

I'm developing a SvelteKit application and I have a couple pages, some of them should be public and others should have a session cookie (otherwise they should be redirected to /login), something like this:

```
/ -> root page, need session cookie or redirect to login
/invoices -> need session cookie or redirect to login
/login -> public access
/signup -> public access
```

I was thinking about using the following groups to [breakout of the layout](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/advanced-routing#advanced-layouts-breaking-out-of-layouts) that checks for cookies

```
src/routes/
│ (app)/
│ ├ +layout.server.ts // checks for session cookie or redirects to /login
│ ├ +page.svelte   // root page
│ ├ invoices/
│ │ ├ +page.svelte  // /invoices page
│ (public)/
│ ├ +layout.svelte  // public layout, does not check for session cookie
│ ├ login/
│ │ ├ +page.svelte  // /login page
│ ├ signup/
│ │ ├ +page.svelte  // /signup page
└ +layout.svelte    // layout common to all pages
```

The other approach I thought about was to have something like this:

```
src/routes/
├ +layout.server.ts // checks for session cookie, unless path is login or signup
├ +page.svelte   // root page
├ invoices/
│ ├ +page.svelte  // /invoices page
├ login/
│ ├ +page.svelte  // /login page
├ signup/
│ ├ +page.svelte  // /signup page
```

That means, in the `src/routes/+layout.svelte` I should have a list of public endpoints for which I should skip cookie verification. By default pages should be protected.

Is there any other approach I might be missing? Is any of them more "correct" than the other?

Comment: I believe you mean `+layout.server.js` not `+layout.svelte`. If that piece of logic is solely about cookie setting, I personally will go second approach, since it unifies cookie-related code in one place, easier for future maintenance.

Comment: you are right, sorry, my mistake, and I tend to agree with you, mostly because for the moment is rather too simple to start complicating it with group routes